# Openstack - Connectivity issues in projects other than admin default project

Tags: networking, project, openstack, connectivity, microstack

I have successfully installed Microstack version of Openstack. After days of digging around I have been able to create vms in the admin (default) project that :

- Access the internet
- Are accessible for hosts in the same LAN as the Microstack installation host

Moving on to testing multiple users with multiple projects I run upon the following issue:

a. I create a new project (**my-project**) through the admin account

b. I create a new network **my-internal** through the admin account in the new project

c. I create a new router **my-router** through the admin account in the new project

d. I attach an interface on the **my-router** router to the **my-internal** network

e. I add two cirros vms to the **my-internal** network

The two vms are able to ping each other.
None of the two vms is able to ping the interface of the router **my-router** that is attached to **my-internal** network (and of course cannot connect to outside).

If I follow the exact same process a->e in the admin project (that already exists after installation) everything functions properly.

It seems that there is a project permissions thing already set up for admin project that I do not do for **my-project** project.

Does anybody has an idea what I am missing??

Comment: Do I understand you right: The two Cirros VMs are owned by *my-project*, and all the networking resources are created and owned by *admin*? If so, I would perform steps b to d in *my-project* and try again. Also, I don't see the step that connects the router to the external network; could it be that you forgot it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I have resolved the issue. Just to leave it here for future reference the problem was that:

Default security group is initiated for each new project.

In my case I had in mind the edited default security group I had in my **admin** project, while for the **my-project** the default security group was initiated form scratch and I had to add rules there.